# Serverless offline + DynamoDb local issue

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, amazon-dynamodb-local, serverless-offline

I've been playing with serverless offline and dynamodb local lately.
When I've used websockets - things worked well.
Then, I've decided to change protocol to http. Don't know how this can be related, but it's the only change I've did in the code.

Now, I receive error from dynamodb (including output of db command):

```
Serverless: [AWS dynamodb 400 0.034s 0 retries] query({
  TableName: 'DEVICE_TABLE_DEV',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#id = :id',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#id': 'deviceId' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':id': { S: 'a1173b07-af44-450b-b709-902c0b011df2' } }
})
ResourceNotFoundException: Cannot do operations on a non-existent table
```

I've checked existing tables with command:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8042
```

And I see, that table exists:

```
{
    "TableNames": [
        "DEVICE_TABLE_DEV",
        "USER_TABLE_DEV"
    ]
}
```

Then I've printed dynamodb client, and I see, that options provided seems to be correct according to documentation:

```
DocumentClient {
  options: {
    region: 'localhost',
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:8042',
    attrValue: 'S6'
  },
  service: Service {
    config: Config {
      credentials: [SharedIniFileCredentials],
      credentialProvider: [CredentialProviderChain],
      region: 'localhost',
      logger: [CLI],
      apiVersions: {},
      apiVersion: null,
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:8042',
      httpOptions: [Object],
      maxRetries: undefined,
      maxRedirects: 10,
      paramValidation: true,
      sslEnabled: true,
      s3ForcePathStyle: false,
      s3BucketEndpoint: false,
      s3DisableBodySigning: true,
      s3UsEast1RegionalEndpoint: 'legacy',
      s3UseArnRegion: undefined,
      computeChecksums: true,
      convertResponseTypes: true,
      correctClockSkew: false,
      customUserAgent: null,
      dynamoDbCrc32: true,
      systemClockOffset: 0,
      signatureVersion: null,
      signatureCache: true,
      retryDelayOptions: {},
      useAccelerateEndpoint: false,
      clientSideMonitoring: false,
      endpointDiscoveryEnabled: undefined,
      endpointCacheSize: 1000,
      hostPrefixEnabled: true,
      stsRegionalEndpoints: 'legacy'
    },
    endpoint: Endpoint {
      protocol: 'http:',
      host: 'localhost:8042',
      port: 8042,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      pathname: '/',
      path: '/',
      href: 'http://localhost:8042/'
    },
    _events: { apiCallAttempt: [Array], apiCall: [Array] },
    MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: EVENTS_BUBBLE],
    CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE],
    _clientId: 1
  },
  attrValue: 'S6'
}
```

This is how I create a client:

```
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'localhost', endpoint: 'http://localhost:8042'});
```

**UPDATE:** adding my serverless.yml dynamodb section configuration:

```
dynamodb:
  # If you only want to use DynamoDB Local in some stages, declare them here
    stages:
      - local
    start:
      port: 8042
      inMemory: true
      heapInitial: 200m
      heapMax: 1g
      migrate: true
      seed: true
      convertEmptyValues: true
    # Uncomment only if you already have a DynamoDB running locally
      noStart: true
```

Would appreciate any advice in this direction.

Comment: List tables by `dynamo` instead of aws cli.

Comment: @hoangdv I've did, and I don't see tables. The question is why? What am I missing to target it properly to localhost?

Comment: `region: 'localhost'` looks odd to me. I still initialise with the real `region` even if I'm targeting a local DynamoDB, e.g. `{ region: 'eu-west-2', endpoint: 'http://localhost:8042'}`. Also you have set `noStart: true`, just to confirm, are you starting your local DynamoDB separately? Did you define your DynamoDB tables in `serverless.yml` or elsewhere?

Comment: @yvesonline yes, dynamodb is started separately, initially region was non localhost as well. This is something I've found in official docs. Tables are also defined, but actually, in this case looks like it tries to read from elsewhere, not the defined ednpoint.

Comment: @yvesonline actually, just double checked without region property. And something changed. Feel free to post answer, at least the above mentioned issue is no longer topical.

Comment: Glad it helped @Lazyexpert , will post as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't init DynamoDB with `region: 'localhost'`.

Either leave it out or change it to a proper region, e.g.:

```
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'eu-west-2', endpoint: 'http://localhost:8042'});
```